# form.$valid always returning false angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-meteor

I'm trying to make validations to my form in an ng-repeat which now always returning as false even though all the inputs are filled and correct.

Here's my update function:

```
$scope.updateChannel = function (channel) {
  if (channelForm.$valid) {
    Channels.update({
      _id: channel._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        name: channel.name,
        category: channel.category,
        tags: channel.tags,
        logo: channel.logo
      }
    }, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('unable to update the channel: ' + error);
      } else {
        console.log('Done! ' + data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('fix errors');
  }
}
```

and here's my form:

```
<form ng-show="channel.edit == true" name="channelForm" ng-submit="updateChannel(channel)" novalidate>
  <md-input-container>
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="channel.name" md-maxlength="20" required>
    <div ng-messages="channelForm.name.$error;">
      <div ng-message="required">Esto es requerido.</div>
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Demaciados carácteres.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label for="category">Categorias</label>
    <md-select name="category" ng-model="channel.category" multiple required>
      <md-option ng-repeat="kit in kits" value="{{kit.name}}">{{kit.name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div class="errors" ng-messages="channelForm.category.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Esto es requerido.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container>
    <label for="number">Canal</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" ng-model="channel.number" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" maxlength="5" required>
    <div ng-messages="channelForm.number.$error;">
      <div ng-message="required">Esto es requerido.</div>
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Demaciados carácteres.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container>
    <label for="tags">Tags(separar con espacio)</label>
    <input type="text" name="tags" ng-model="channel.tags" md-maxlength="20" required>
    <div ng-messages="channelForm.tags.$error;">
      <div ng-message="required">Esto es requerido.</div>
      <div ng-message="md-maxlength">Demaciados carácteres.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-input-container>
    <label for="logo">Logo</label>
    <input type="text" name="logo" ng-model="channel.logo" required>
    <div ng-messages="channelForm.logo.$error;">
      <div ng-message="required">Esto es requerido.</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>

  <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="channel.edit = false" ng-disabled="channelForm.$invalid">Guardar</md-button>
  <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="channel.edit = false">Cancelar</md-button>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="removeChannel(channel)">Borrar</md-button>
</form>
```

now this is in an `ng-repeat="channel in channels"` so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Also, all the ng-messages seem to be working correctly and even when none of them are showing I'm still unable to update the document.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a ng-repeat, you will end up with a bunch of forms named `channelForm`

You could put a new controller on the form tag and move `updateChannel` in that controller.

Comment: wouldn't that call multiple times the same controller? How would this affect performance?

Comment: The controller will be instantiated separately for each form tag, giving them independed scopes. If there is any initialization code, it will run for each form, so keep it minimal. On submit, only the code in the associated controller will be invoked.